# Bind class in Vue.js based upon array of booleans

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-reactivity

I have a series of text fields with a button next to each field. When the user taps the button next to one of the fields I want to apply a particular style to that button (to change its colour) - essentially allowing the user to "tick" that they have checked that field (similar to a checklist).

There are nine text fields/buttons on the page, and I have the status of all the buttons stored in an array called `items_checked` which is initialized in `data()` as the following:

```
items_checked: [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]
```

Each button has the following code:

```
 <button class="btn btn-danger" v-on:click="toggleChecked(0)" v-bind:class="{'itemChecked' : items_checked[0]}">
```

where the number indicates the index of the button (i.e. 0 is the first button, 1 is the second button, etc.) to correspond to the equivalent boolean in `items_checked`.

The `v-on:click` event just toggles the checked status in the `items_checked` for the tapped button:

```
toggleChecked (itemIndex) {
  if (this.items_checked[itemIndex] === false) {
    this.items_checked[itemIndex] = true
  } else {
    this.items_checked[itemIndex] = false
  }
  console.log(this.items_checked)
}
```

This works as the `console.log` shows the boolean values toggling.

However, the `v-bind` does not work as the `itemChecked` class does not get applied to the button. It seems to be an issue binding to a boolean value within an array, as when I bind just to a standard boolean declared within `data()` it works fine.

I do eventually need all the checked statuses stored in an array, so that I can evaluate that all have been checked before allowing the user to submit the page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is common [reactivity problem](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats).

In document:

> Due to limitations in JavaScript, Vue **cannot** detect the following
> changes to an array:
>
> When you directly set an item with the index, e.g.
> `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`

> When you modify the length of the
> array, e.g. `vm.items.length = newLength`

You can use deep copy

```
toggleChecked (itemIndex) {
  this.items_checked[itemIndex] = !this.items_checked[itemIndex]
  this.items_checked = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.items_checked))
  console.log(this.items_checked)
}
```

Another solution is using `Vue.set`

```
toggleChecked (itemIndex) {
  var oldValue = this.items_checked[itemIndex]
  this.$set(this.items_checked, itemIndex, !oldValue)
  console.log(this.items_checked)
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks so much! Being new to Vue.js I completely missed that reactivity problem in the documentation.